# Does Java's String.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") return the first byte of each 2-byte character in a string?

Tags: java, android, unicode

I thought UCS-2 to ISO-8859-1 was the same as

```
    rawData = new byte[data.length()];
    for(int i=0; i<data.length(); i++) {
        rawData[i] = (byte)(data.charAt(i) & 0xff);
    }
```

This seems to be false. Why isn't the above code equivalent to `data.getBytes("ISO8859_1")` instead? I'm on Android.

In fact, it turns out that some of my characters were `0xf700 & (byte)`. For some reason this happens when you fetch a binary file with `XMLHttpRequest` and `Charset: x-user-defined`. When converting to `latin1` those characters turn into `?` (question marks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per thw Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29):

> The behavior when this string cannot be represented in the named charset is unspecified.

In practice, this call ends up as the variant that takes an explicit `Charset`, which will substitute some replacement sequence for untranslatable characters. In the Sun JDK, this is a single-byte value 64 ('?').

However, in your comment to the earlier answer, you guarantee that there are no character values greater than '0xFF' in the string, then you're doing something wrong. ISO-8859-1 is a proper subset of UCS-2/UTF-16.

Comment: Nah, it would be a "proper subset" if the strings resulted in the same bytes when encoded by `UTF-16` and `ISO-8859-1`, which it obviously does not.

Comment: I could be doing something wrong. I will double check by comparing the two bytes[] from the two different approaches.

Answer (score 2):

The reason was already explained by parsifal's answer. Just for completeness, here is the code which is equivalent to `data.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")` (assuming the string is a pure UCS-2 string, no surrogate pairs):

```
byte[] rawdata = new byte[data.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    char c = data.charAt(i);
    if (c > 255) {
        rawData[i] = (byte)'?';
    }
    else {
        rawData[i] = (byte)c;
    }
}
```

With surrogates (e.g. real UTF-16) it gets a bit more complicated:

```
byte[] rawData = new byte[data.length()];
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++, j++) {
    int c = data.codePointAt(i);
    if(c < 0x100) {
        rawData[j] = (byte)c;
    }
    else {
        rawData[j] = (byte)'?';
        if(c >= 0x10000) {
           // surrogate pair
           i++;
        }
    }
}
if(j < rawData.length) {
   rawData = Arrays.copyOf(rawData, j);
}
```

Alternatively, just using `charAt()`:

```
byte[] rawData = new byte[data.length()];
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++, j++) {
    char c = data.charAt(i);
    if(c < 0x100) {
        rawData[j] = (byte)c;
    }
    else {
        rawData[j] = (byte)'?';
        if(Character.isHighSurrogate(c) && Character.isLowSurrogate(data.charAt(i+1))) {
           // surrogate pair
           i++;
        }
    }
}
if(j < rawData.length) {
   rawData = Arrays.copyOf(rawData, j);
}
```